# ORMLite one-to-many relationship of itself

Tags: android, ormlite

I have a model that has a one-to-many relationship of itself. Every time I run my android application, I keep getting an `SQLException` that states that my Foreign Collection class `Route` for my field `childRoutes` column-name does not contain a foreign field of class `Route`. I feel like I specified this already in my Model but I may be missing something?

Here is my model excluding the getters/setters:

```
public class Route implements Serializable{

@DatabaseField(id = true, canBeNull = false, columnName = "id")
private long id;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "parent", foreign = true)
private Route parent;

@ForeignCollectionField
private ForeignCollection<Route> childRoutes;

}
```

I followed this question here but I still can't seem to be getting it right.
[ORMLITE one-to-many recursive relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497117/ormlite-one-to-many-recursive-relationship)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have solved the issue by replacing `private ForeignCollection<Route>` to just `Collection<Route>`. I'm not quite sure why it's not working if I use ForeignCollection as the type, but it seems to fix all my issues.